# collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I Hava a class called VarianteValore this class have a collection of Foto, the primary key of VarianteValore is a multiple compositeId.
Now when Map my class NHibernate return me the exception above.
i'm struggle with the mapping solution by day, but i haven't found a solution yet.

below my Class and Mapping

```
 public class VarianteValore : EntityBase
{
    #region Private
        private ICollection<Foto> _immagini;
    #endregion

    public virtual VarianteProdotti VarianteProdotti { get; set; }
    public virtual GruppoAttributi GruppoAttributi { get; set; }
    public virtual AttributiValore AttributiValore { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Foto> Foto
    {
        get { return _immagini != null ? _immagini : new List<Foto>(); ; }
        set { _immagini = value; }
    }

    public virtual double OffSetPrezzo { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        VarianteValore id;
        id = (VarianteValore)obj;
        if (id == null)
            return false;
        if (this.Id == id.Id && this.VarianteProdotti.Prodotti == id.VarianteProdotti.Prodotti && this.GruppoAttributi.Attributi == id.GruppoAttributi.Attributi)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.Id + "|" + this.VarianteProdotti.Prodotti + "|" + this.GruppoAttributi.Attributi).GetHashCode();
    }

}

  public class Foto : EntityBase
{
    public virtual VarianteProdotti VarianteProdotti { get; set; }
    public virtual GruppoAttributi GruppoAttributi { get; set; }
    public virtual Prodotti Prodotti { get; set; }
    public virtual string Path { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Pubblicata { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsVideo { get; set; }
    public virtual int Position { get; set; }

    public virtual string Alt { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        Foto id;
        id = (Foto)obj;
        if (id == null)
            return false;
        if (this.Id == id.Id && this.VarianteProdotti == id.VarianteProdotti)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.Id + "|" + this.VarianteProdotti).GetHashCode();
    }
}

 public class VarianteValoreMap : ClassMap<VarianteValore>
{
    public VarianteValoreMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
           .KeyReference(x => x.VarianteProdotti, "Prodotti_Id", "VarianteProdotti_Id")
          .KeyReference(x => x.GruppoAttributi, "Prodotti_Id", "Attributi_Id");

        //FK AttributiValore 
        References(x => x.AttributiValore, "AttributiValore_Id");

        HasMany(x => x.Foto).KeyColumns.Add("Prodotti_Id", "VarianteProdotti_Id", "Attributi_Id");

    }
}

public class FotoMap : ClassMap<Foto>
{
    public FotoMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        References(x => x.VarianteProdotti).Columns("Prodotti_Id", "VarianteProdotti_Id", "Attributi_Id");
        Map(x => x.Path).Length(400);
        Map(x => x.Pubblicata);
        Map(x => x.IsVideo);
        Map(x => x.Position);
    }
}
```

I hope the code below can ilustrate better. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Foto should reference its parent instead of its parents id parts

```
public class Foto : EntityBase
{
    public virtual VarianteValore VarianteValore { get; set; }
...
}
```